# Persist meta box choices throughout all posts of same post type

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions

I have a custom post type for which I want to create either a meta box or an ACF field. The user can then specify three posts of the same post type to be featured on a page. The links have to persist between posts, what I mean by that is that if I declare post a, b, and c to be the featured articles, and I hit save, I want to be able to go to a different article and see the same three choices in the box. 
That way I can always be sure that there will be at most 3 articles featured on the page.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is this a front-end user? If so, and if the user is logged in then you can store the article IDs in their user meta. If not, you'll probably have to use a cookie to store the IDs. Or is this an admin user? In that case the featured post IDs can either go in the blog meta, or as flags on the posts, or as a separate post object that just contains these IDs, or something else - there are plenty of options.

Comment: The featured articles would ultimately be displayed on the front-end, where the logged in status doesn't matter. I think a cookie can only be set once I have a solution that lets me persists data throughout all posts, though? How do I create a post object that saves and loads the same data on all posts?

Comment: Just to clarify - if you're saying that you are editing post A, and you select posts B, C, and D, then when you edit post B, C, or D, you also see those same selections - yes, you can do that. ACF calls it "bidirectional relationships" which basically link posts to each other from both directions. However, if you are talking about editing any Page and you want to see a specific set of postmeta that is more of a global setting, what you will want to do instead is to create an ACF options page where you select the 3 featured posts. That way there's only 1 place to manage them.

Comment: @WebElaine To clarify: I select B, C, and D on post A. I want B, C, and D to show on ALL the other posts. I use ACF Pro and don't see a birelational option. I do see "relationship" under Field Type, but the 3 links I select on one post don't show on any of the other posts. The query i would like to run on the front-page is "show me all post names tagged as featured, but allow only 3 to be featured at a time."  I just started on an ACF options page, but since you mentioned it was global I would rather have an option that was as local as possible. Can you elaborate on the bidirectional relation?

Comment: If you want something "global" bidirectional is definitely not what you want. It simply applies postmeta to all the associated posts. It would not provide a way for all the other (non featured) posts to show what posts are featured. An options page would give you 1 single place to set the featured posts so you could be sure only a certain max are set at any given time.

Comment: @WebElaine Would you recommend to make the options page, create a Link ACF group on there, manually enter 3 links, and then use queries on the front-end to fetch the rest of the data? That's how I preliminarily designed it, and the field group on the options page is a 'post-object` as the field type, so that I can work with the full object. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I would definitely go with an ACF options page. The data type is up to what works for you. I think I personally would just save the post IDs rather than the full post objects, because I tend to also pull in things like featured images that aren't part of the post object. It just depends on which information you want to show on the front end, and how you want to format it; sounds like you've got a good setup for what you are looking to achieve.